# Experience using Wowza Media Server for Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, streaming, video-streaming, flash-media-server

**Question 1:** WHat have people's experiences been with using Wowza Media Server 2 for Amazon EC2  (http://www.wowzamedia.com/ec2-streaming.html)

We're planning to use it to allow streaming experience for all of our stored videos (which are on S3).

**Question 2:** I'm specifically interested in knowing how many connections the EC2 instance can handle before balking...

I'll be setting up the flowplayer as follows on my server

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    flowplayer("player", "../flowplayer-3.2.4.swf",
        {
            clip: {
                url: 'mp4:amazons3/videos/thevideofile.mp4',
                provider: 'rtmp'
            },
            plugins: {
                rtmp: {
                url: '../flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.3.swf',
                netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://999.999.999.99/vods3'
                }
                        }
        }
    );
</script>
```

where 999.999.999.99 will be the EC2 instance

**Question 3:** IF the EC2 instance (referenced via the rtmp://) is inaccessible, would the video be completely unplayable?

Answer (score 1):

1. Wowza for EC2 works fine and you have builtin support to mount S3-buckets in the system so that shouldn't be an issue at all. The amount of connections can handle before balking is according to recommendations.

   - EC2 Small 150 mbs (Which is approximately 600 250/kbs streams)
   - EC2 Large 225 mbs (Approx. 900 250/kbs streams)
   - EC2 X-large 350 mbs (Approx. 1400 250/kbs streams)